# unable to perform click in osascript

Tags: osascript

I'm attempting to simulate a click on screen with this osascript:

```
tell application "System Events"
       click at {1500, 850} -- {from left, from top}
end tell
```

results in `System Events got an error: An error of type -25200 has occurred.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was clicking "off the screen" here.  If you take a screenshot it says the screen is 2900x1800, but when you do "screen capture select" (cmd+shift+4) apparently the true max (bottom right of screen) is 1400x900 and it takes the "relative" numbers.